# React-native 0.57 ios limits file not found could not build module CoreFoundation

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

**RN 0.57.1**

**RN-cli 2.0.1**

**xCode: 9.4.1 (9F2000)** or **xCode 10**

After an update of RN from 0.56 to 0.57.0 (or 0.57.1) I get a lot of `could not build module 'CoreFoundation'` or `could not build module Foundation` or `limits file not found`

I followed exactly the steps from RN doc for this update.

I tried removing `ios/build` folder, cleaning cache, re-installing everything but nothing worked.

> ▸ Building BunteMobile/OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension [Debug] ▸
>   Check Dependencies ▸ Compiling NotificationService.m
>
> /Users/myuser/Desktop/projects/mobileapp/ios/../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/fabric/graphics/platform/ios/float.h:8:10:
>   'limits' file not found
>
> `#include <limits>`
>
> /Users/myuser/Desktop/projects/mobileapp/ios/../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/fabric/graphics/platform/ios/float.h:8:10:
>   'limits' file not found
>
> `#include <limits>`
>
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator11.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6:10:
>   could not build module 'CoreFoundation'
>
> `#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>`
>
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator11.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Headers/SecBase.h:28:10:
>   could not build module 'CoreFoundation'
>
> `#include <CoreFoundation/CFBase.h>`
>
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator11.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/Headers/CFNetwork.h:18:10:
>   could not build module 'CoreFoundation'
>
> `#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>`
>
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator11.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UserNotifications.framework/Headers/NSString+UserNotifications.h:8:9:
>   could not build module 'Foundation'
>
> `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>`

If I remove the OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension instead of 7
 errors I get another 15 errors in other parts of the project:

> /Users/myuser/Desktop/projects/mobileapp/ios/../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/fabric/graphics/platform/ios/float.h:8:10:
>   'limits' file not found
>
> `#include <limits>`
>
> /Users/myuser/Desktop/projects/mobileapp/ios/../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/fabric/graphics/platform/ios/float.h:8:10:
>   'limits' file not found
>
> `#include <limits>`
>
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator11.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6:10:
>   could not build module 'CoreFoundation'
>
> `#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>`
>
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator11.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Headers/SecBase.h:28:10:
>   could not build module 'CoreFoundation'
>
> `#include <CoreFoundation/CFBase.h>`
>
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator11.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/Headers/CFNetwork.h:18:10:
>   could not build module 'CoreFoundation'
>
> `#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>`
>
> /Users/myuser/Desktop/projects/mobileapp/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include/React/RCTBridgeModule.h:8:9:
>   could not build module 'Foundation'
>
> `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>`

The only workaround that I found is to downgrade RN back to 0.56...

According to the RN team answer from here
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/21482

changing all babel deps to 7 should fix the issue but even after an `npx babel-ugrade -w` and a reinstall of node modules + cache clean I get the same errors.

but still same problems.

Should any with header search paths be updated in extensions/ios build settings after update to 0.57?

I've spent 3 days with this IOS building issue....

Note: I was able to build android after the upgrade of RN and babel.

React-native git associated ticket:
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/21482

Comment: I have a similar problem with RN 0.57 & lottie-react-native sometimes... Usually, I fix it by re-starting my computer, as `npm install`,  `pod install` , DerivedData or build folders cleaning didn't seem to work. ReactNative builds ARE fragile things...

Comment: We did it many times and doesn't work!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To fix all these errors I had to remove **React** and **ReactCommon**  from `Project Header Search paths` and from `OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension target header search paths`.

**1) Removing from project header search paths:**

The crashes were related to `limits`, `CoreFoundation`, `Foundation` and `CoreGraphics`.

I went to `Project Header Search Paths` and removed the React and ReactCommon dependencies from there.

This is how my `project header search paths` looks now:
[image]

**2) Removing from one-signal extension:** (Optional, if you don't have any extension you don't have to do this)

This is how the paths of that extension used to look when crashing:
[image]

This is how the target of that extension looks now:

[image]

**Note: I haven't changed anything in the `project target header search paths`.**

I am not sure what changed in RN 0.57, why it was crashing now in 0.57, how this `header search paths` should be in extensions, project and target. Why previously having React and ReactCommon there worked and why now it is not working anymore.

My project was created 3 years ago and had many RN updates. It is possible that at some point React and ReactCommon were needed in the project header search paths.

As I wrote in my question, this problem was signaled in RN github too,
more details can be found here:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/21482#issuecomment-427815231